# Unable to hit AWS SQS api from postman

Tags: postman, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create a queue in SQS by hitting at their api using Postman. I have already created IAM account and generated the key corresponding to the user. Still, I am getting the access denied error. following is the post request that I am trying to hit

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/MyQueue/
?Action=CreateQueue
&QueueName=MyQueue
&Attribute.1.Name=DelaySeconds
&Attribute.1.Value=45
&Expires=2020-12-20T22%3A52%3A43PST
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

I have entered a proper combination of accessKey and secretKey and all other required field. I am getting the error

```
<AccessDeniedException>
<Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be 
 authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

Their is no way to make the queue public on SQS. Same response is coming on trying any different method. Any leads will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove "MyQueue/" from URL. The right code should like the following:

```
https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
?Action=CreateQueue
&QueueName=MyQueue
&Attribute.1.Name=VisibilityTimeout
&Attribute.1.Value=40
&Expires=2020-10-18T22%3A52%3A43PST
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

For more info:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html

Comment: I think you also want to remove the "12345..." number.  This works for me:

https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com?Action=CreateQueue&DefaultVisibilityTimeout=0&QueueName=Test&Version=2012-11-05